# Reducing redundant codes in serializers.SerializerMethodField()

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

my post serializer returns **top comments** and **the number of comments**

I marked the redundant code below.

```
class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    comment_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            ...
            'comments',
            'comment_count',
        )
    # showing the most recent comments
    def get_comments(self, obj):
        content_type = obj.get_content_type <<
        object_id = obj.id <<
        comments = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(obj)[:2] <<
        return CommentSerializer(comments, many=True).data

    # showing the number of comments
    def get_comment_count(self, obj):
        content_type = obj.get_content_type <<
        object_id = obj.id <<
        comments_count =  Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(obj).count() <<
        return comments_count
```

It works fine by itself but I don't want to query N x 2 rows whenever it hits the PostDetailSerializer

```
expected output is below
    .....
    "comments": [
        {
          ...
            "content": "Edited!",
          ...  
        },
        {
            ...
            "content": "New wwaa!",
            ...
        }
    ],
    "comment_count": 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could minimize the amount of queries by prefetching the comments with the post. To try it you could play around with changing your queryset in the view to

```
Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('comment_set')
```

Where comment_set should be your reversed aka related_name (I'll re-use comment_set below a couple times).

Then to make it use the prefetches, you might need to change

```
Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(obj)[:2]
```

to

```
obj.comment_set.objects.all()[:2]
```

I don't know the internals of prefetching, but I'd expect the comments to be prefetched with that obj already so this wouldn't need a new query then.

I would expect the count could also be run from the prefetches when you use

```
obj.comment_set.objects.count()
```

Interested to hear if this helps to get the query count down! Also, beware that prefetching could also hurt performance in some cases, there's some interesting articles on it on the web.

Comment: Prefetching won't do any good, since for each method he's performing separate `filter()` queries would result in ignoring prefetched data.

Comment: Let me try and test it for performance.. I think zaidfazil is right

Comment: Yes that's why I suggested not to use filter_by_instance and instead query it from the object that prefetched the comments. I'm pretty confident that will bring your query count down.

Comment: thanks for adding more explanation. Just accepted your answer. Can you try this question too? I think you can solve this problem too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340864/can-you-optimize-this-code-django-python