# Can you optimize this code? (Django, python)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I'm adding 'added' field to check which categories User's Post(Outfit) is added to. It sounds horrible, so let's dive in to the code.

**I want to optimize get_categories(self, obj) function.**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    added = serializers.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'added'
        )


class OutfitDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def get_categories(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        categories = Category.objects.filter(owner=user)
        added = categories.extra(select={'added': '1'}).filter(outfits__pk=obj.pk)
        added = list(added.values('added', 'name', 'id'))
        added_f = categories.extra(select={'added': '0'}).exclude(outfits__pk=obj.pk)
        added_f = list(added_f.values('added', 'name', 'id'))
        categories = added + added_f
        return CategorySerializer(categories, many=True).data
```

The output is below!

```
"categories": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Gym",
        "added": true
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "School",
        "added": false
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "hollymo",
        "added": true
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Normal",
        "added": false
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "New Category",
        "added": false
    }
]
```

Here is models.py

```
class Outfit(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    outfits = models.ManyToManyField(Outfit, related_name="categories", blank=True)
    main_img = models.ImageField(
                            upload_to=upload_location_category,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True)
    ...
```

here the [repo for test](https://github.com/gitavk/category)

Comment: it will be better to add your models to the current question, more readable for other people

Comment: alright just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you right, you can get necessary data with [django raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries):

```
q = """\
SELECT yourappname_category.id,
       yourappname_category.name,
       COUNT(outfit_id) > 0 as added 
FROM yourappname_category
  LEFT JOIN yourappname_category_outfits 
      ON yourappname_category.id = yourappname_category_outfits.category_id 
         AND yourappname_category_outfits.outfit_id=%s
WHERE yourappname_category.owner_id=%s
GROUP BY yourappname_category.id, yourappname_category.name"""

categories = Category.objects.raw(q, [obj.id, user.id])
results = [{'id': c.id, 'name': c.name, 'added': c.added} for c in categories]
```

Comment: how `Category` with `"added": false` will be in your query? what is your logic? OP get it by `added_f = categories.extra(select={'added': '0'}).exclude(outfits__pk=obj.pk)`

Comment: @devxplorer Can you explain it more?

Comment: @BearBrown It will LEFT join outfits with specified id, then grouped by category and count outfits items for category, if category have no outfits it will get COUNT(outfit_id) > 0 as false. But maybe I did not fully understand what the author wants

Comment: @JohnBaek please see comment above, and tell please did you tried this, did it return correct results?

Comment: @devxplorer i test your solution, it's wrong, [repo for test](https://github.com/gitavk/category)

Comment: @BearBrown understand, I'll look more precisely today

Comment: @BearBrown, check plz [my fork](https://github.com/devxplorer/category/tree/so_46340864), i added tests to check original func and my sql query returns the same results and rewrote query for postgres.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm out of town so I'll be back in 24 hours from now. And I'm glad @BearBrown tested it for me. big thanks

Comment: @devxplorer you cool! i was test your solution manual,  and make error, sorry!

Comment: @BearBrown no problems)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly you just want "to check which categories User's Post(Outfit) is added to". For that you would only need to return the ones with added = true right? and then you could leave the added key out.

as in:

```
"categories": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Gym"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "hollymo"
    }
]
```

If so, you could just use:

```
import Category from category.models

class CategoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class OutfitDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = CategoriesSerializer(many=True)
```

If instead your use case is to show a list of all categories and then do something with just the ones that the current outfit is added to, I'd suggest doing 2 API calls instead of your current logic; One with the answer I supplied above and one to get all categories. Then do that 'added' logic in your front-end as its presentation layer logic imo.

I'd certainly try to avoid doing raw SQL queries in Django, it cuts the purpose of migrations and is rarely necessary.

Comment: the code in the question works correctly, but currently OP want to know is there a way to minimize query to database.

Comment: I see, and for that the answer of using raw SQL might be correct (I was certainly not trying to bash that answer!). But I think the code in question might not be how you'd best set up your API architecture in terms of performance, so I suggested to reconsider the output instead of trying to create it.